# Background service Thread is run on some phone but some phone not

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I make one app in that I write service which detect the wifi network and send data to server, for that I write Alarm Manager and broadcast receiver and then through alarm manager and broadcast receiver call service onCreate method. My code below:

BootCompletedIntentReceiver class call broadcast receiver with 30sec.

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent background = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, background,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            // start 30 seconds after boot completed
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
            // fetch every 30 seconds
            // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
            service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(),2000, pending);


        }
    }
```

AlarmReceiver Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(background);
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);


            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            CharSequence tickerText = "Service Started";
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon,tickerText, when);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            CharSequence contentTitle = "Service Start!";
            CharSequence contentText = "";
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
            // Log.d("test", "Saving Data to File from Service.");
    }

}
```

From AlarReceiver service gets call and first onCreate method and then OnstartCommand.. And I write thread to detect the wifi.. This code is run for some phone but some phone service never start. why this is happened??

My Manifest file code is below:

```
<service android:name="com.edbeans.attendance.MyService"
                 android:enabled="true" 
                 android:process=":my_process" 
                 android:exported="true"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></service>

         <receiver android:name="com.edbeans.attendance.AlarmReceiver">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
         <receiver android:name="com.edbeans.attendance.BootCompletedIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Why this is happened that service gets call from some phone and successfully run but some phone service never starts..

Comment: Use exactRepeating alarm!

Comment: which part has not run on some phones and also please tell us on which phone you got result and on which phone you got no results

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I already Used in BootCompletedIntentReceiver class.

Comment: @CoasMckey Run on my company's some local tab and my frnd's mobile of samsung model number GT-I8552.

Comment: @kiko283 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750860/unable-to-access-internet-via-wifi-from-a-background-service?answertab=active#tab-top I Tried your code And its working absolutely correct. But I have One doubt in that how can I set Alarm to check continuously after 5sec. In your code.

Answer (score 1):

The system may go back to a low power state immediately after your alarm received has run. In order to ensure that your `Service` runs you need to coordinate between the `BroadcastReceiver` and the `Service` using a wakelock. Check out the `WakefulReceiver` as an option to help with this.

Comment: This article will help explain alarms and the demo code has an example :http://hiqes.com/android-alarm-ins-outs/